# Component library HTML basic does not contain datatable

Tags: jsf, web

I am creating a datatable using JSF pages but when I am trying to create one I am getting an error Component library HTML basic does not contain datatable, I have no idea why it doesn't contain this feature. I couldn't find anything to help this error through other sources.

```
       <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
       <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"                                    "          "http:        //www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
       <ui:composition template="/Template.xhtml" >
         <ui:define name="content">
             <h:panelGrid>
              <h:datatable value ="#{//somecode}">
                       </h:panelGrid>
                     </ui:define>
                </ui:composition>
           </h:body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you show what have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't tried anything, I don't even know how to start solving this error

Comment: Hello! Please take a look in the 'How to ask' guide: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question. Including an attemp you have made would help greatly because then members can comment on improvements, and aditions you can make.

Comment: [This](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_display_datatable.htm) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I was using datatable instead of the component dataTable